# Make deb-package which updates another deb-package

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I have a deb package of my Software. It has a many files and weights a lot. (Let's name this software-1.0.0.deb ~ 1Gb)

I want to create a service pack deb-package which includes only several updated files. (Let's name this software-1.0.1.deb ~ 5Mb)

So this new package should increment the version of the package (I will have Software 1.0.1 installed) and correctly handle the update.

How can I do it correctly?